# Excel Formula to Check for Overlaps in Day and Time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am building an Excel spreadsheet for weekly class schedules. There are 3 columns where people input a schedule in the following format: "[day] [starttime] [endtime]"

Example:

| no. | day | start time | end time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MTh | 7:00 AM | 9:00 AM |
| 2 | TF | 7:00 AM | 9:00 AM |
| 3 | M | 8:30 AM | 9:30 AM |

**In this example, what I want is for Excel to highlight rows 1 and 3, because they have a time overlap on Monday**

I'm looking for a formula that I can also put inside conditional formatting.

So far, I am only able to highlight time overlaps but have not considered the day. I used a SUMPRODUCT formula below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((M15<$N$15:$N$26)*(N15>$M$15:$M$26))>1
```

Where M15 is start time and N15 is the end time. The N column range refers to all the end times and M column range refers to all the start times

As much as possible I'd like to use Excel formulas and avoid any VB scripting. But if it's not possible with only formulas, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Is the day column Monday & Thursday on row 1, Tuesday & Friday on row 2 and Monday on row 3?  Might be a bit problematic to split the days if that's the case - "T" is Tuesday unless it's followed by an "h" and ignore "h" unless it's preceded by a "T".  Saturday & Sundays occur as well?

Comment: Hi @DarrenBartrup-Cook. Sorry I forgot that detail, but yes, Row 1's schedule is every Monday and Thursday. I made another helper column that converts "Th" to just "H" to avoid confusion with "Tuesday" and make it all single characters: "M, T, W, H, F, S". Saturdays are included, but not Sunday.

Comment: Question duplicated on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1670072/excel-formula-to-check-for-overlaps-in-day-and-time).

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98hJG1C5Hx825Y-uj?e=mAMy6e)/screenshots refer:

**Outside of conditional formatting**

[image: Boolean flag in cells / outside of conditional formatting]

```
=(B2:B7<=G2)*(C2:C7>=G1)*(A2:A7=G3)
```

---

**Within conditional formatting GUI:**

*Step 1 - formula construct:*

[image: Step 1 - formula]

```
=($B2<=$G$2)*($C2>=$G$1)*($A2=$G$3)
```

*Step 2 - application over desired range:*

Straightforward step:

[image: Step 2 - apply conditional format]

---

**Notes**

- Notice - sumproduct is superfluous/unncessary (I find this is generally the case, and sum often works just as well as sumproduct as 'one level up' from approach/functions I've presented here)
- If having a common formula for both 'outside' and 'within' conditional format framework is central to objective, then use 'within' formula in both cases (and simply drag down over desired range 'outside')
- Key differences (outside vs within conditional formatting):
- Outside: formula encompasses both 'condition' and 'range' over which it applies (thus, leveraging an array, no need to 'fix' cell references with 'bullet' i.e. $ signs)
- Within: here, formula constructed for specific cell (usually convenient to do so using upper left in relation to a contiguous block over which it shall be applied); the second step 'applies' this condition over a specified range.  Ramifications include: arrays wouldn't usually feature in the formula construct 'step'; and bulleted references can be pertinent for successful 'application' in next step
- *Bonus: whilst you mentioned already having a 'conversion' table re: day name / label references (i.e. M = Mon, S=Sat etc) have a look at the approach I've used which determines this list within a single cell (provided schedule is ordered appropriately, it may be useful for this/related applications)*
- ="("&CHOOSE(MATCH(G3,A2:A7,0),"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat")&")"

Comment: Might I ask what's the use of the additional columns F and G? I see that it is referenced in the formula.

Comment: F&G: per the link I provided in opening line - this merely references 'start' and 'end' times - I believe these were referred to as M15 and N15 in OP version *"Where M15 is start time and N15 is the end time"*.  During my testing, I created validations lists for different times/days - these are not essential to soln - OP can replace with M15 and N15 as req.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this unhandy

> *array-formula which needs to be confirmed through <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>*.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT((LEN(SUBSTITUTE($L$15:$L$24,"Th","H"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($L$15:$L$24,"Th","H"),$K$1:$P$1,"")))*(ROW($K$15:$K$24)<>ROW()),TRANSPOSE(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(L15,"Th","H"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(L15,"Th","H"),$K$1:$P$1,"")))))*(N15>$M$15:$M$24)*(M15<$N$15:$N$24))>0
```

And you currently need to put `M T W H F S` in cells `K1` to `P1`.

| 1 | MTh | 7:00 AM | 9:00 AM | TRUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | TFS | 7:00 AM | 9:00 AM | TRUE |
| 3 | M | 8:30 AM | 9:30 AM | TRUE |
| 4 | T | 10:00 AM | 11:00 AM | FALSE |
| 5 | MS | 8:30 AM | 11:00 AM | TRUE |
| 6 | WH | 1:00 PM | 2:00 PM | FALSE |
| 7 | MWHFS | 12:00 AM | 1:00 PM | TRUE |
| 8 | H | 2:00 PM | 3:00 PM | FALSE |
| 9 | MW | 11:00 AM | 1:00 PM | TRUE |
| 10 | H | 4:00 PM | 5:00 PM | FALSE |

It can't be used for conditional formatting as it is an array-formula, but you can use conditional formatting on the results of the formula.